# Selenium - Java : PhantomJS : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpVerb

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to instantiate a PhantomJS Driver with Selenium Java. Below is the code :

```
     File file = new File("C:\\Softwares\\drivers\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");               
     System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());       
     WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();  
     driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

I have tried with different versions of Selenium and I am getting the same exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpVerb
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/HttpVerb
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.getCustomCommands(PhantomJSDriver.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.<init>(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:110)
```

I'm using the below list of dependencies in my project :

1. phantomjsdriver
2. selenium-common.jar
3. selenium-java 2.53.1 . jar

The reason I'm using an outdated version of selenium library is due to some article I found over the internet saying that remote/HttpVerb is deprecated and downgrading the library would remove the error. However, I'm still getting this error

Comment: is ur problem solved??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this dependancy in POM

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Check whether this class is present or not

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I have added the dependency and still not working.

Comment: is it works for u? I have used 2.48.2 standalone jar it is woking fine

Comment: I checked for the class HttpVerb in the library. It is not present. No, still the issue persists.

Comment: Add it into the dependamcy

Comment: Does this version have the class present in the library?

Comment: I am using 2.48.2 standalone jars it runs. Downgrade the jars and try

Comment: use phantomjsdriver-1.2.1 if use 2.53

Comment: I used a combination of  phantomjs - 1.2.1; selenium-java - 2..53.0; and selenium remote driver. This worked